# xcode archive is failed

Tags: swift, xcode, archive

I'm really struggling when archive my app
I tried so many solutions such as restart xcode and mac, upgrade to the latest xcode, clean build, pod update, delete DerivedData...
However, I still got failed when I tried archive my app.

[image: failed specific libararys...]

[image]

Do you have any ideas to solve this situation?

Comment: Did you look in the Issue navigator to see what the problem is?

Comment: @matt yes I looked issue navigator but I only got that message 'Command ComplieSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code'

Comment: So you can build to a specific device, and you can do a Release build to a specific device, but you cannot archive to a generic device??

Comment: @matt you are right, build and run on device is works fine. only when archive to device, I for above errors which is on library